# Compare struct in C

Tags: c

I'm learning structs in C and I don't know a convenient way to reach my time struct to test if it is midnight.

The "if" line has syntax error (`error: expected expression`):

```
if (UpdatedDaT.stime == { 0, 0, 0})// If midnight 
        UpdatedDaT.sdate = dateUpdate(DaT.sdate)
```

Here is some code from my program:

```
struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};
struct time
{
    int hour;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

struct dateAndTime
{
    struct date sdate;
    struct time stime;
};

struct dateAndTime clockKeeper(struct dateAndTime DaT)
{
    struct dateAndTime UpdatedDaT = { .stime = timeUpdate(DaT.stime) };

    if ( UpdatedDaT.stime == { 0, 0, 0} )// If midnight 
        UpdatedDaT.sdate = dateUpdate(DaT.sdate);
    else
        UpdatedDaT.sdate = DaT.sdate;

    return UpdatedDaT;
}
int main(void)
{
    struct dateAndTime DaT;
    printf("Enter date and time (mm dd yyyy hh:mm:ss): ");
    scanf("%i %i %i %i:%i:%i", &DaT.sdate.month, &DaT.sdate.day, &DaT.sdate.year,
        &DaT.stime.hour, &DaT.stime.minutes, &DaT.stime.seconds);

    struct dateAndTime UpdatedDaT = clockKeeper(DaT);

    printf("\nThe UpdatedDaT is %i/%i/%.2i %.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n",
        UpdatedDaT.sdate.month, UpdatedDaT.sdate.day, UpdatedDaT.sdate.year,
        UpdatedDaT.stime.hour, UpdatedDaT.stime.minutes, UpdatedDaT.stime.seconds);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not valid C syntax - you can only compare structs element-by-element.

Change:

```
if (UpdatedDaT.stime == { 0, 0, 0})// If midnight
```

to:

```
if (UpdatedDaT.stime.hour == 0 &&
    UpdatedDaT.stime.minutes == 0 &&
    UpdatedDaT.stime.seconds == 0)// If midnight
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't compare structures with `==` (nor should you use `memcmp`).

The best way is to write a custom comparison function that compares two struct objects of the given type. It is recommended to do so in the form of a function that returns an integer smaller than zero, zero or larger than zero, if the first struct is considered smaller, equal or larger than the second struct.

Use the following format:

```
int compare_date (const void* obj1, const void* obj2)
{
  const date* d1 = obj1;
  const date* d2 = obj2;
  int diff;

  diff = d1->year - d2->year;
  if(diff != 0)
    return diff;

  diff = d1->month - d2->month;
  if(diff != 0)
    return diff;

  diff = d1->day - d2->day;
  return diff;
}
```

The advantage of this form is that you can now use this function together with standard library functions `bsearch`, `qsort` and similar. Those functions is the reason for the void pointers - it is a generic, type-independent way of writing comparison functions in C. (Sometimes these are referred to as "functors".)

Comment: I am curious that why are you not using the obj1 and obj2 diectly specifying as const date * ?

Comment: Hm, still I'd created a typed version of the compare-function in the 1st place, wrapping the untyped version around it. Why lose the advantage of compile-time type checking for the cases *not* using `qsort()` and `bsearch()`?

Comment: @Mazhar Because this is a generic format. By using `const void*` we use the form that functions like `bsearch` want. Essentially, by using the above form we got searching and sorting algorithms for free. This is sometimes known as a "functor". Check out how the `bsearch` function works and it should become clear.

Comment: @alk Then use the advanced version `#define compare_date(obj1, obj2) 
  _Generic ((obj1), date*: _Generic((obj2), date*: comp_date))(obj1, obj2)`, where `comp_date` is the comparison function.

Answer (score -1):

A more convenient way is to use Memory compare function i.e. `memcmp`

First define and initialize a default variable that you will be using for checking along with you other data like this

```
/* To zero out everything */
memset(DefaultDaT, 0, sizeof(DefaultDaT));
memset(UpdatedDaT, 0, sizeof(UpdatedDaT));

DefaultDaT.stime.hour = 0;
DefaultDaT.stime.minutes = 0;
DefaultDaT.stime.seconds =0;
```

And then simply compare like this

```
if (memcmp(DefaultDaT, UpdatedDaT, sizeof(DefaultDaT)) == 0) // If midnight.
```

Comment: In general this is a very bad idea, since it might fail in unpredictable ways as soon as there is padding in the structure. I would really not recomment this unless you know what you're doing and are aware of the dangers.

Comment: @unwind Yes, Padding could create problem if the user is unaware of it. Moreover even if user provide the structure size including the padding, then due to garbage values in the padding can cause this to behave differently.

Comment: @unwind This is classic Unix programming practice. It is, however, also classic Unix programming practice to make sure the padding is properly initialized to 0 by doing a `memset` or `bzero` on the structure once it is allocated. Some of the classic Unix socket libraries work exactly that way.

Comment: @tofro Saying "it is classic Unix programming" is hardly the same thing as saying "this is good programming practice". In fact it is sometimes the opposite. Regardless, telling newbies to use `memcmp` is definitely a bad idea.

Comment: At the very least update this answer with the struct initialization code, so we can tell that the example isn't buggy.

Comment: @Lundin I didn't claim this to be "good programming practice" - It is the only way, however, that you can, for example, properly use the Unix socket API - Unix doesn't seem to care about your opinion here...